# curl -I option not working

Tags: http, curl

curl -I gives 503 error while curl -v gives 200.
What can be the root cause?

eg-

```
curl -I -k https://myurl
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
```

```
curl -k -v https://myurl
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Answer (score 5):

The root cause is the server being stupid and it doesn't like HEAD requests although it should. As [RFC 7231 section 4.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) says about HEAD:

> The server SHOULD send the same header fields in response to a HEAD
> request as it would have sent if the request had been a GET, except
> that the payload header fields MAY be omitted.